# How does one use the WebGreaseTask MSBuild Task from WebGrease?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild-task, webgrease

In [the documentation for WebGrease, it talks about using an MSBuild task](https://webgrease.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebGrease%20build%20task) to do minification at build time. However, when I add the task to my project file, it fails.

Here are the lines I've added to my project

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="WebGreaseTask" AssemblyName="WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
  <Target AfterTargets="DotLessBuildTasksDotNet" Name="Minify">
    <WebGreaseTask />
  </Target>
```

But when I try to build, I get the following error:

> The "WebGreaseTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL. Could not
>   load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

As far as I know, that's the correct assembly name, as I'm using the same reference in my project:

```
<Reference Include="WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And all of the code there is working fine.

I want to do the minification at compile time, which I believe is the purpose of the build task. I know there are a plethora of bundling and minification helpers out there, but I'd like to avoid pulling in more packages than I have to.

Edit:

I've tried the various NuGet commands, but those don't affect the `UsingTask` node in any way, and don't cause the build to work either. Still at a loss on this error.

Comment: Looking in the source code there is a class https://webgrease.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WebGrease/WebGrease.Build/WebGreaseTask.cs which looks like the thing you need, but after decompiling my local WebGrease nuget package, I don't see this class or WebGrease.Build assembly there at all. As the error points out it can't find a class that implements ITask and this class exactly implements it.

Comment: Thanks, @VsevolodGoloviznin, that's what I was afraid of. It seems a bit odd that the error says it can't load the file, when in fact it can load the file, it's just that the file doesn't have the appropriate code.

Comment: I will post this as an answer then, in case somebody will be stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the source code there is a class https://webgrease.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WebGrease/WebGrease.Build/WebGreaseTask.cs which looks like the thing you need, but after decompiling my local WebGrease nuget package, I don't see this class or `WebGrease.Build` assembly there at all. As the error points out it can't find a class that implements `ITask` and this class exactly implements it.

Comment: I'm going to let this answer marinate until closer to the expiration to see if I can get any other responses. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the only way I see is manually including this library into the project, but then why do we need nuget for :)